# Function Builder not working when only one value?

Tags: swift, swift5

I have a functionBuilder

```
@_functionBuilder
struct MyBuilder {
    static func buildBlock(_ numbers: Int...) -> Int {
        var result = 0
        for number in numbers {
            result += number * 2
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Function

```
func myFunc(@MyBuilder builder: () -> Int) -> Int {
    builder()
}
```

use

```
let a = myFunc {
    10
    20
}
print(a) // print 60 is work!
```

but

```
let b = myFunc {
    10
}
print(b) // print 10?
```

Why is b not 20?

I try add other buildBlock

```
static func buildBlock(number: Int) -> Int {
    return number * 2
}
```

But not working :(

Any idea?

Comment: Interesting question, I tried to make it work, but I failed either:) In fact, you can change your implementation of `buildBlock` to one line: `numbers.reduce(0, { $0 + $1 * 2 })`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any idea?

What is happening in the failing case is that `{ 10 }` is being treated as a closure of type `() -> Int` directly and the compiler doesn't appear to consider the function builder at all. The code that is produced is simply a function which returns `10`.

This appears to a "feature" where the recognition of `{ 10 }` as a simple closure overrides its possible recognition as a use of the function builder. This may just be a compiler issue or worse it might be a language definition problem...

Please head to feedbackassistant.apple.com and file a report.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is correct, it is just passing the value and ignoring the builder.

But [it's a bug, not a feature](https://twitter.com/dgregor79/status/1258412048934768641).

It's fixed on Swift 5.3, which is only available on Xcode 12 (currently in beta).